# ORA - 01722 Error When using Partition Over and To_Char

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am relatively new in the SQL world and I am trying to gain as much knowledge possible. This one has me stumped. All of our data is compiled in a Oracle Database but the reports we create as from SSRS through Visual Studio 2005. This is the problem. I have a query to helps separate data by using parameters that convert the date to string so the user can select the date at the top of the report. The query for that is:

```
select type_type,
        RCD_REASON,
        rc.description,
        MATERIAL_ID,
        USERID,
        DATETIME_SCRAPPED,
        ORDER_NUMBER,
        TRIMDATE,
        SUBSTR(SALES_ORDER,3,8) || '-' || SUBSTR(SOL_LINE_NUMBER,3,4) AS SalesOrder,
        QTY,
        COMPONENT_MATERIAL_ID 
from WORKCELL.history hh 
inner join WORKCELL.reason_codes rc
  on hh.rcd_reason = rc.reason
where rc.type_type in ('FAB','TRM') AND TO_CHAR(DATETIME_SCRAPPED,'YYYYMMDD') between to_char(:FromDate,'YYYYMMDD') AND to_char(:ToDate,'YYYYMMDD')
```

Where the FromDate and ToDate are the parameters.

I made some adjustments to the query as so:

```
select type_type,
           RCD_REASON,
           rc.description,
           MATERIAL_ID,
           USERID,
           DATETIME_SCRAPPED,
           ORDER_NUMBER,
           TRIMDATE,
           SUBSTR(SALES_ORDER,3,8) || '-' || SUBSTR(SOL_LINE_NUMBER,3,4) AS SalesOrder,
           QTY,
           COMPONENT_MATERIAL_ID , 
           row_number() over (partition by  SALES_ORDER, ORDER_NUMBER order by DATETIME_SCRAPPED) as rn

    from WORKCELL.history hh 
    inner join WORKCELL.reason_codes rc
    on hh.rcd_reason = rc.reason
    where rc.type_type in ('FAB','TRM') 
   AND to_char(DATETIME_SCRAPPED,'YYYYMMDD') between to_char(:FromDate,'YYYYMMDD') AND to_char(:ToDate,'YYYYMMDD')
```

and now I get this ORA-01722 error for an 'invalid number'. Can anyone explain why this is happening? When I hardcode the date in, the query runs fine, but for some reason the parameters break it now. And yes, I must have these parameters in the query for SSRS.

Comment: Check the description of WORKCELL.reason_codes for the type_type column type. Is it a varchar?

Comment: That doesn't seem to make sense on first look. How are the results being consumed - is there an outer query, or is the caller restricting based on `rn` directly? Have you maybe added an implicit conversion to number as you retrieve a column - maybe just an index error? Feels like there is something missing from the picture though...

Comment: @mmmmmpie both reason_code and type_type are both varchar column types.

Comment: @AlexPoole I wish I could give you all the pictures. Our database setup is a little wonky because it consists of everyone's own view of how it should be managed, so things are harder to work around. Aside from MmmmmmPie's suggestion, I just couldn't figure out why the top query will play fine with SSRS but the bottom will not.

Comment: @AlexPoole the rn serves a purpose to easily sum duplicates in my SSRS file. by calling the value in the rn column

Comment: @JimmieN is this the whole query? Or just a part of it? Which line exactly shows the error? is this part of a stored procedure?

Comment: @ypercube that is the whole query and there is not a stored procedure. When I am given the error in SSRS, they do not specify which line gives the error, just the error code. I can't replicate the error in oracle since I am not Parameters when I run it there.

Comment: First, I'd go for stripping away those `to_char`s, meaning `trunc(datetime_scapped)` instead of `to_char(DATETIME_SCRAPPED,'YYYYMMDD')`, then `trunc(:FromDate)`, then `trunc(:ToDate)` and for making absolutely sure that the calling tier binds those two really as `date`s. At first sight, those places are the only ones which could cause such an error. (Of course, there are second, third, ... sights, too.)

Comment: Also, (a second sight) the `workcell.history` and `workcell.reason_codes` ... Is any one of them a view containing an aggregation?

Comment: @nop77svk Ill try that and see. I will keep you posted on my findings

Comment: (A third sight ...) The `hh.rcd_reason` and `rc.reason` are both of the same datatype?

Comment: @nop77svk truncating the dates worked perfectly!

Comment: Too bad I don't know absolutely exactly what went wrong (and then well) in this case, only guessing, so I can't post a regular answer for your question. Anyway, I'm glad to have helped.